# Difference in window.location.protocol and window.isSecureContext?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, javascript-objects, window.location, secure-context

In JavaScript you can check whether the url/website accessed is over `Http` or `Https`, via 2 ways

1. `window.location.protocol` which returns `http:` or `https:`
2. `window.isSecureContext` which returns `true` for `https` and `false` for `http`.

I know that `window.isSecureContext` is non-standardised. But lets say I know it is available at the client browser.

Then,

1. what is the difference between the two read-only values? Which one to use?
2. Most Importantly, In which case would there be an anomaly. Meaning, first method says `https:` while second says `false` or other way around.

Comment: seems the isSecureContext  is only a Boolean return of (window.location.protocol==='https'). You need to use window.location.protocol because other is not full browser implemented

Comment: `window.location.protocol` could return more values like `ftp:`, `mailto:`

Answer (score 2):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Secure_Contexts :

> A context will be considered secure when it's delivered securely (or locally), and when it cannot be used to provide access to secure APIs to a context that is not secure. In practice this means that **for a page to have a secure context, it and all the pages along its parent and opener chain must have been delivered securely**.
>
> For example, a page delivered securely over TLS is not considered a secure context if it has a parent or ancestor document that was not delivered securely, since otherwise the page would then be able to expose sensitive APIs to the non-securely delivered ancestor via postMessage messages. Similarly, if a TLS delivered document is opened in a new window by an insecure context without noopener being specified then the opened window is not considered to be a secure context (since the opener and opened window could communicate via postMessage).
>
> Locally delivered files such as http://localhost and file:// paths are considered to have been delivered securely.

(Emphasis mine)

Answer (score 1):

```
window.location.protocol
```

returns a string containing the protocol of the website you are browsing at the moment. it could be "https", "http", "file" for local HTML files...

It does mean that it is secure.

```
isSecureContext
```

on the other hand, returns a boolean, `true` if it is secure, or `false` if it isn't.

Take for example a simple static HTML page with "file" protocol. If you type into the console "isSecureContext", it will return true. A locally served web app "localhost" will return true too, although these last two are not served on an "https" protocol.

So yes. The two options are indeed different from each other.